# Basic probability theorem

Tags: probability

Given $P(A) = 0.5$ and $P(A \cup (B^c \cap C^c)^c)=0.8$.

Determine $P(A^c \cap (B \cup C))$.

I know from DeMorgans law that: $(B^c \cap C^c)^c = (B \cup C)$.

Edit:

Also how can I "prove" that P(X)=P(Y) if and only if $P(X \cap Y^c) = P(X^c \cap Y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\begin{align}P\bigl(A^c\cap(B\cup C)\bigr) &= P(A^c\cap A)+P\bigl(A^c\cap(B\cup C)\bigr)\\ &= P\bigl(A^c\cap (A\cup B\cup C)\bigr)\\ &= P\bigl((A\cup B\cup C)-A\bigr),\end{align}$$ and that if $A$ occurs, then $A\cup B\cup C$ occurs. Thus, $$P\bigl(A^c\cap(B\cup C)\bigr)=P(A\cup B\cup C)-P(A).$$ This is even easier to see with a Venn diagram.

For the second bit, use the fact that $P(X)=P(X\cap Y)+P(X\cap Y^c)$ and $P(Y)=P(X\cap Y)+P(X^c\cap Y).$

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $X:=B\cup C$, as you noted, we have $P(X\cup A)=0.8$ and $P(X\cap A^c)=P(X\setminus A)$ is the question. For this, use that $X\setminus A$ and $A$ are disjoint and that $(X\setminus A)\cup A=X\cup A$. (All gets clear once you draftly draw them..)
2. As $X\cap Y$ is disjoint to $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c$ and their union is $X$, we have 
   $$P(X)=P(X\cap Y)+P(X\setminus Y)\,.$$
   Also write it for $Y$. This implies the second statement.

Comment: Nice picture of the proof.